# getStaticProps vs getServerSideProps : what's the difference in the real world?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is an old question that I didn't understand. I know that getStaticProps is rendered at build time and getServerSideProps is rendered at run time, But in real example I'm really confused and I don't know which one to choose : I have studied this article(https://medium.com/eincode/next-js-data-fetching-getstaticprops-vs-getserversideprops-fcbf43d0ccac), But it seems doesn't apply to my project:

I have an online shop project, Imagine this: I have dynamic search page to show search result and I used getServerSideProps in it and I have dynamic category page that shows lots of each category using getStatic props.
This is my Category Page:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import https from "https"
import Lots from "../../lots"
import { GetStaticPaths,GetStaticProps } from 'next';
 const LotsInCategory = ({data}:{data:Array<any>}) => {
   
  return (
    <>
    {console.log(data)}
    <Lots lots={data}/>
    </>
  )
}

axios.defaults.httpsAgent=new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized:false,
})

export const getStaticPaths:GetStaticPaths=async()=>{


 
  let paths:Array<any>=[]
  try{
   const response=await axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`)
   paths=await response.data.map((el:any)=>({params:{category:el.category.toString()}}))
  
  
  }
  catch(er){
    
  }

  return{
    paths,
    fallback:true
  }

}
export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps=async(context:any)=>{
  let data:Array<any> =[]
  try{
    const response= await axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categsdfdsory/${context.params.category}`)
    data=response.data
    alert("x")
  }
  catch(er:any){

  }
  return{
    props:{data},
    revalidate:2
  }
}
// export const getServerSideProps=async(context:any)=>{
//     console.log("x")
//     const response=await axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/${context.params.category}`)
   
//   let data=response.data
//   console.log(data)
   
//   //   const data={
//   //     id:context.query.id,
//   //     title:context.query.title,
//   //     image:context.query.image,
//   //     description:context.query.description,
//   //     rate:context.query.rate,
//   //     count:context.query.count,
//   //     price:context.query.price,
    
//   // }
  
  
  
  
//   // data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
//   return {
    
//     props:{data}
     
   
//   }
//   }
export default LotsInCategory
```

And here is the search page:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import https from "https"
import { constants } from 'http2'
import Lots from '../../lots'
 const SearchResult = ({data,value}:{data:Array<any>,value:string}) => {
     data=data.filter((el,i)=>{
         return el.title.toUpperCase().includes(value.toUpperCase())||el.category.toUpperCase().includes(value.toUpperCase())||el.description.toUpperCase().includes(value.toUpperCase())
     })
  return (
      <>
      {console.log(data)}
      {console.log(value)}
    {data.length==0 ? (
          <h2>there is nothing matches your search</h2>

    ):(
        <Lots lots={data}/>
    )}
    </>
  )
}

axios.defaults.httpsAgent=new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized:false,
  })
export const getServerSideProps=async(context:any)=>{
    let data=[]
    try{
        const response=await axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`)
         data=response.data
    }
    catch(er){

    }
    return{
        props:{data,value:context.params.value}
    }

}
export default SearchResult;
```

According to article above about getStaticProps:

1-`This method is primarily used inside a page to fetch data at build time`.(It's ok)

2-`Once the app is built, it will refuse to refresh the data till the time another build has been run`.

It doesn't work in my project. If I use dev mode (npm run dev), When I change data in category page (for example `https://fakestoreapi.com/productsdssfasf` instead of ``https://fakestoreapi.com/products`), It doesn't refuse to refresh data after refreshing the page! In the other side If I use product mode(npm run build and npm run start),Both of the search and category pages refuse to refresh data till the time another build has been run. So what's diffrence?!

3-`The advantage of using GetStaticProps is that it lets the page be statically generated. As a result, out of all the available data fetching methods, GetStaticProps generates the fastest load times.`

It also doesn't work in my project . Category pages and search pages have the same load speed!
the article also says that GetStaticProps lets the page be statically generated, But what does it mean? If it means it accepts static address in dynamic routes (for example accepting `/users/` instead of `user/${id}`), It's not true because when I type `localhost/category` instead of `localhost/category/${categoryName}` I see 404 pages!

Please help me to understand items 2 and 3 and help me to understand when I should getStaticProps and when I should getServerSideProps.

Answer (score 4):

GetStaticProps (gsp), getServerSideProps (gssp)

1. If you have some dynamic content that user wants to see immediately, i.e they change something in their profile settings and then go there, then you want to use gssp. Otherwise, with gsp you'll see a stale content, even with revalidation. It can heavily hurt UX.
2. If it's , for example, an online store page, i.e. a page that is visited frequently, it's rational to use gsp + revalidation (static server generation (SSG)), because in this case you keep the page load speed and at the same time its content freshness.
3. If it's just some static content, then use gsp

Answer (score 2):

as per [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#runs-on-every-request-in-development), in development, getStaticProps is called on every requests.

This means that in dev, SSG and SSR are functionally equivalent.

> In development (next dev), getStaticProps will be called on every request.

Because you have configured `fallback: true` in your `getStaticPaths` function, `getStaticProps` will also run in production for paths that were not generated at build time.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true

Comment: tnx@Christian. I  understand that SSG and SSR are functionally equivalent in dev mode. I configured fallback:false but I steel receive 404 page. It seems SSG and SSR also have  the same behavior in production mode. both of them refuse to refresh data without rebuild and both of them return 404 page when you type wrong address! so what's difference in production mode?

Comment: if you have configured `fallbacl: false` then getting a 404 page for an un-generated path is the expected behavior.

I'm unsure why your `getServerSideProps` function isn't called on every request in prod. Could be caching related but I don't see any caching directives added in your code. Have you tried adding a `console.log` statement at the top of the method to see if it gets hit?

Comment: So let me check if I understand: you believe that you getServerSideProps must be called  on every request. I added console.log at the top of the page. But I can't see this without rebuild!

Comment: when you say at the top of the page do you mean at the top of the function? The log statement needs to be inside the `getServerSideProps` function. I just tried it and the log statement is output on every refresh of the page after running `npm run start`

Comment: Sorry for delay in response @christian .Yes I wrote console.log inside the main component instead of getServerSideProps function. Now I putted log statement  in the getServerSideProps function and I can't see anything in my browser because it's ssr

Comment: @bami that is expected. You won't see any log statements in the browser console. `getServerSideProps` runs on the server side so you need to check the server logs to verify that the function is getting called.

Comment: I can't see log statements in the terminal.  Do I need to install any extensions or something like that to show server logs?

Comment: @bami Try the following steps: 1) Add a `console.log` inside the `getServerSideProps` function in a page component; 2) Start the dev server with `npm run dev`; 3) Load the page  in the browser where you have the `getServerSideProps` setup; 4) Go back to the terminal where you started the development server (`npm run dev`), and verify that the `console.log` is there.

Comment: @juliomalves tnx this worked , But can I have log statement in product mode?

Comment: @bami Yes, just do the exact same steps but build/run the prod build instead with `npm run build && npm start`.

Comment: @ChristianHagelid according to juliomalves guide I checked log statemant in getServerSideProps (in  production mode) and when I changed log statement and used npm start and refreshed the page , I didn't see  any changes without rebuild!

Comment: @bami Like any other code change, if you change the log statement you will need to rebuild the app to see the reflected changes in the prod build.